# PyCharm: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been trying to scrape data from websites using selenium in Python (3.7.4 for 32-bit).

The script runs through properly and it is supposed to concatenate the columns (using numpy) and then write the data frame into .csv files.

However, PyCharm (2018.3.7) gives me following error code at some point of the data scraping:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

I could not find anything specific about the error code. Does anyone know why it would occur?

Comment: I suggest to update your IDE and try again

Comment: You should provide the code that will generate the issue, so people can see what you're actually using - without it, answering will be very hard if not impossible.

Comment: @LinPy I am using Win 7 32-bit, this is why I need to use older PyCharm version for it to function.

Comment: @Grismar I suspected it to be a PyCharm problem, not a script problem since it does not cause any errors.

Comment: @JenG I don't think it is, although it's hard to say without more information. Can you provide more information about when and how the error occurs? I.e. a screenshot of a popup dialog with a description of when it happens, or whether the error shows up in the console (and whether this is the only line that appears)?

Comment: @Grismar it occurs at some point when the script runs for x hours. I print some output in the console and then suddenly this line appears: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` which is the only error

Comment: @jeng the error message in your original question and the one you just quoted are not the same. At any rate, they likely don't occur anywhere in Python code, nor do I think it's thrown by PyCharm itself (you'd see it pop up, not in console). The most likely candidate for this seems to be Selenium. Perhaps it is logging something useful? If not, I think you should be able to get Selenium to log more, so if it happens again, you may get some useful information about what went wrong at the time. `0xC..135` is a initialisation error, `0xC..005` is an access violation.

Comment: @Grismar that is a really good hint! Thank you I'll try that!